# How to get exact browser version in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the exact browser version of google chrome using codeigniter.
I tried it using the "User_agent" library of codeigniter. However I got the browser version as 110.0.0.0, where my actual version of chrome is 110.0.5481.177.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance

My code is

```
 $this->load->library('user_agent');



$browser_version = $this->agent->version();
```

Comment: The User Agent string can contain anything at all. It might contain some or all of the browser version, or it might contain any arbitrary string. Some crawler regularly visits our corporate web site with the agent string "Hello, world". Whatever you're using this for, consider a different way.

Answer (score 0):

User agent does not contain the exact browser version. Even if you use PHP `get_browser` function or JavaScript `navigator.userAgent` property you will get the same result.